# Javascript not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am noob at this one so I wanted to ask you if you maybe know how to select all elements except one.

Here is script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jump = function (e) {
        //prevent the "normal" behaviour which would be a "hard" jump
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the target
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        //perform animated scrolling
        $('html,body').animate({
            //get top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
            //scrolldelay:1 seconds
        }, 1000, function () {
            //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
            location.hash = target;
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
        return false;
    });
</script>
<!-- // end of smooth scrolling -->
```

And I want to do same effect on all links except #myCarousel . Question is how to do that and where needs to be included :not selector in script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/), like:

```
$('a[href*=#]').not('#myCarousel').bind("click", jump);
```

Comment: This has solved my problem.

                  $(document).ready(function()
                  {
                         //$('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
                         $('a[href*=#]').not(document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control")).bind("click", jump);     
                         return false;
                  });

Answer (score 0):

You can use :not in the selector itself.

```
$('a[href*=#]:not(#myCarousel)').bind("click", jump);
```